# ListAdded is not firing when list is created by code

Tags: event-receivers, splist

I have an SPListEventReceiver that handles the ListAdded event. If checks that the list is a Document Library, and then adds some fields to the library:

```
public class ListEventReceiver : SPListEventReceiver
{
    public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
    {
        if (properties.List.BaseTemplate == SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary)
        {
            // Add fields here
        }
        base.ListAdded(properties);
    }
}
```

When a list is created using SharePoint's web UI, the event works perfectly.
However, when the list is created by the code below, the event is not fired, and the fields are not added:

```
SPWeb spWeb = ...;
SPListTemplate listTemplate = ...; //Find relevant DocLib template
Guid newListId = spWeb.Lists.Add(title, description, listTemplate);
```

**EDIT: I do not have the option of changing the EventReceiver - it was created by a third party, and I have no control over it.**

Comment: Not sure it will help you but move `base.ListAdded(properties);` before your custom code. Can you debug and verify that your event is fired and condition is met?

Comment: What kind of library do you try to create? Some document libraries have different `SPListTemplateType` (not only `DocumentLibrary` which has code 101, but other codes).

Comment: @Kai - just the regular DocLib, with 101 code

Answer (score 2):

ListAdded event runs asynchronously (whereas ListAdding is synchronous). The properties may not be available for updating. This post describes an alternative using ListAdding - [Working with ListAdding and ListDeleting Events](http://www.sharepointbriefing.com/spcode/article.php/3851211/Working-with-ListAdding-and-ListDeleting-Events.htm).

I had a similar Event handling situation with ItemAdded/ItemAdding in a Document library where it worked fine under UI but not for automated upload (using PowerShell). There is a matter of at which point in the event handling the properties should or can be updated. This post explains the various Events and their variations ('-ing', '-ed', etc) - not all properties are available during the synch/asynch event handling - [Managing ItemUpdating and ItemUpdated Events](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/managing-itemupdating-and-itemupdated-events-firing-twice-in-a-sharepoint-item-event-receiver/)

More on getting ListAdded (-ed event handling) to run synchronously - [SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers can be Synchronous or Asynchronous](http://www.sharepoint2007security.com/blog/2010-05-21/sharepoint-2010-event-receivers-can-be-synchronous-or-asynchronous)

UPDATE:
Looking at the update to the question above ("EDIT: I do not have the option of changing the EventReceiver - it was created by a third party, and I have no control over it.").
The solutions may be limited as I presume, you do not have access to the event handler code. You may try this change - you can specify the 'ListAdded' event handler as synchronous in its Elements.xml file (within the Receiver tag) - Synchronous.

Here's another link to consider should you regain the handler code -
[Binding asynchronous event handlers as synchronous](http://wineya.blogspot.com/2010/03/binding-asynchronous-event-handlers-as.html)

Comment: Does it really matter since in question it is stated that if list is created using UI everything works fine?

Comment: also test if you can specify the 'ListAdded' event handler as synchronous in its Elements.xml file thus (within the Receiver tag) -
<Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>

Comment: Vedran - please see my edited response above. Thanks. SBC.

Comment: You missed my point. If everything works fine when adding list via UI (event fires, fields are added) then IMHO sync is not an issue. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Vedran - as mentioned above: the UI procedure worked for a manual upload but not during automated upload. Asynchronous events by its nature are non-deterministic.

Comment: Document upload is sooooo specific that I don't think it applies here. But I will not be so deterministic to rule out your answer. Don't get me wrong but your initial answer was a bit confusing to me so I needed to clear things out. Let's wait for @ItaySagui feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain, but do you have to fire an spWeb.Update() after the add?

And should make sure you have using for  your SPWeb object, not modifying directly. eg:

```
 using(SPWeb oWebsite = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb("Website_URL"))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SPContext.Current to get your SPWeb? Be sure you're using properties.Web or such in an event receiver. If the code isn't being run on the UI thread, SPContext.Current would be null.